# Hard drive shows up for `lsblk` but not `fdisk`

Tags: hard-disk

I have a hard drive (`/dev/sda`) that is visible when I run `sudo lsblk -f`, but not when I run `sudo fdisk -l`.

What could be causing this?

All the google results I could find were about drives that were not listed with either `lsblk` nor `fdisk`.

edit to add:

When I run `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`, I get the error

> fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Input/output error

Comment: are you running fdisk as root or with sudo?

Comment: Does `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` -> `p` > `Enter` work?

Comment: I am running `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: When I try running `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`, I get the error `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Input/output error`.

Comment: Additional information: I get an Input/output error when I try to run `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo lsblk /dev/sda` and `ls -l /dev/sda` to your question?

Comment: `lsblk` is simply interrogating the drive identify, while `fdisk` actually needs to read from disk. The error you're seeing suggests that your drive may be bad.

Answer (score -2):

Use gdisk. It should work. This means either the disk is physically damaged, but to the extent that is it sill recognised or that partition table has been damaged in a way that fdisk is not able to recognize. fdisk will not let you in, but gdisk will.

Comment: How should gdisk work if the drive is damaged?